# find php 5.6 folder

Tags: php, mongodb, centos

I have a dedicated Centos server.

As I see at plesk it has 5.3 (5.4),5.6 and 7 php but the default php is 5.4
My problem is that I want to install mongo driver for the 5.6 PHP version and I do not know where is 5.6 PHP installed.

Also I need to run some php 5.6 command line scripts.How can I find where php ver. 56 is located at centos server?

Comment: Have you tried the whereis command? whereis php5

Answer (score 0):

Use /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/ path.

Comment: I want to install mongo.so for 5.6.I did it for 5.4 so I copied mongo.so at  /opt/plesk/php/5.6/lib/modules.This did not worked.I have to compile mongo drive as I did for 5.4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following instruction for installation php mongo extension for PHP5.6, for example:

1. Install all necessary packages for compiling mongo module:

yum install make plesk-php56-devel gcc glibc-devel openssl-devel

2. Compile mongo module:

/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/pecl install mongo

3. Add extension to corresponding ini file:

echo "extension=mongo.so" > /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.d/mongo.ini

4. Reread php handlers:

plesk bin php_handler --reread

5. Go to Plesk -> Tools&Settings -> PHP Settings -> 5.6.xxxx
6. Enjoy the view of the installed mongo module.